# Error with Zebra_Calendar and JSON in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins

I'm using the [Zebra_Calendar](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) jQuery plugin on my page, but as soon as I include a `json` implementation, I get an "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method" Error on `string.split` during the initialization when running the page in IE7 mode.

I reduced the error producing code from the json plugin to these lines:

```
(function () {
    if (typeof Date.prototype.toJSON !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.toJSON =
            Number.prototype.toJSON =
            Boolean.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
                return this.valueOf();
            };
    }
} ());
```

This is taken from the standard json implementation found at https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js, but I also got this error on other json implementations.

Now, I don't see the error, but maybe someone else had this problem and has a solution? I need json on my page and I want to use this calendar.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out by myself I think...
Just remove the `Boolean.prototype.toJSON =` from the json code, I haven't found any sideeffects yet. I think it isn't even defined by the ecmascript standard.

So, I hope this is helpful to somebody.